# Java + Active Directory - Single Sign On

Tags: java, active-record, ad

Foi pedido que eu fizesse SSO para uma aplicação web em Java.

A ideia é que através de informações do computador, a aplicação verifique no AD e de acordo com a ***OU*** do usuário, ele tenha acesso a determinados módulos da aplicação.

Já pesquisei coisas como SPNEGO, mas não entendi muita coisa, alguma luz?

Comment: De uma olhada nesse link ai que vai te ajudar [https://github.com/Waffle/waffle](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle) Ai tem a documentação e como implementar.

Comment: Já implementei algo parecido há muito tempo atrás. Se não me engano o protocolo usado para se comunicar com um AD é o LDAP.
Com ele você consegue se conectar no AD, fazer queries, inserir e registrar dados, etc. Alguma luz sobre o que é OU: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756688/what-are-cn-ou-dc-in-an-ldap-search Acredito que basicamente, o que você terá de fazer, é construir uma query que retorne esse usuário, e você verifique se ele possui a OU que você procura.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo utilizar o [Spring Security SAML](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/). No site do Spring tem um case para vc baixar e testar para vc ver como funciona. Eu já fiz isso não é um bicho de 7 cabeças.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas acabei resolvendo com o waffle

Comment: Adiciona uma resposta à tua pergunta com tua solução, assim podemos enriquecer essa pergunta/resposta e atribuir a resposta correta à solução